# GtkColorChooser vs GtkColorSelection

Tags: c, gtk

(Jacked straight from my last thread:) Reading through the [GTK Book](http://www.gtkbook.com/), there are lots of things to clean up when making sure to learn GTK3-focused skills. One is color selection widgets.

First, I'm wondering how GtkColorChooser is supposed to permit alpha choosing. The book just has you `gtk_color_selection_set_has_opacity_control (GTK_COLOR_SELECTION (colorsel), TRUE);`. There's a similar function for `GtkColorChooser`, but it doesn't seem to create anything. There's also the `show-editor` attribute that I flipped to `TRUE` without seeming to do anything.

Second, is there an equivalent notion to `GtkColorSelectionDialog->colorsel` for `GtkColorChooserDialog`? As in, can you access the `GtkColorChooser` widget from the parent dialog?

EDIT:

This is the source for the dialog creation where I'm missing something. I'm expecting this to show me an alpha-enabled color chooser widget, but it only gives me the regular swatches.

```
dialog = gtk_color_chooser_dialog_new(title, window);

gtk_color_chooser_dialog_set_use_alpha(GTK_COLOR_CHOOSER(dialog), TRUE);
```

My only guess is that I'm trying to access the color chooser incorrectly, but I haven't been able to find sufficiently detailed instructions about how to get to the chooser from the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `GtkColorChooser` interface allows choosing the alpha channel by setting the `:use-alpha` property:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkColorChooser.html#gtk-color-chooser-set-use-alpha

when the `:use-alpha` property is set, you can select the alpha when creating a new custom color in the editor; a new scale widget will appear at the bottom of the color editor and will let you select the alpha level:

[image: the GtkColorChooser editor with use-alpha set to TRUE]

the `GtkColorChooserDialog` is a `GtkDialog` with a `GtkColorChooserWidget` inside the dialog's content area, so you can use `gtk_dialog_get_content_area()` and then get the first child of the returned `GtkBox`. this is arguably a layering violation, and should not be needed: `GtkColorChooserDialog` proxies all the `GtkColorChooser` methods to its `GtkColorChooserWidget`, and you should never need to access the widget directly. if you want to keep control of the `GtkColorChooserWidget`, you should create your own `GtkDialog` and pack a `GtkColorChooserWidget` into it yourself. again, I would not recommend doing that unless you want to create your own custom dialog.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the source that's not producing the intended results. You answer is comprehensible and addresses my objective, but I thought the lines appended above would produce the image you've posted. Of course, they don't quite.

Comment: the image I posted is the color editor, which is accessible from the GtkColorChooserWidget by pressing the "custom" button in the palette. that's the only place where you can get the alpha channel editing.

Comment: Aha. Go figure, I never even noticed the "custom" button. And it's enabled by default; cool. =)